# Regarding uiimagepickercontroller

Tags: iphone, ios4

In my application i have to upload a image and that image is taken from the ipad camera,  now my query is when i choose the button "TakePicture" the cameraview opens can I resize the cameraview which captures the image.

Here is my code.

```
- (void) takePicture {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;

    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
    [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont think so, that is an internal ui call,
You might be able to put some custom overlay on the camera view as quite a few other apps do, but to resize the internal camera view is not what apple wants us to do.
But then again, it would be a nice to have as we can use that for some really cool effects!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean view itself? No, the size couldn't be changed. If you mean size of taken/chosen image, user will be allowed to do resizing if you set allowsEditing to YES.